# ¿Cómo mantener relación de aspecto de un elemento según el ancho del padre en CSS?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy haciendo un diseño básico manteniendo la relación de aspecto 2:1 en base al ancho del viewport (vw).

Si tengo  los elementos:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="terrain">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

con las siguientes clases:

```
.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
.terrain{
    width: 80vw;
    height: 40vw; /* uso el ancho del viewport para darle un alto proporcional (80vw/2 = 40)*/
}
```

Por ahora no existe ningun problema ya que esto es un diseño simple...

El problema aparece cuando necesito poner ese elemento con la clase `.terrain` dentro de otro padre que no dependa del **vw**(view width)

No encuentro alguna forma (en CSS) de darle esa proporción al elemento con clase `.terrain` en caso de que su padre tenga un ancho fijo(px) o porcentual(%).

*La pregunta concreta es:*

¿Cómo puedo usar el ancho del padre para darle un ancho y alto al hijo usando CSS sin recurrir a Javascript?

Comment: Lo más sencillo es el uso de % ya que es el % de quien lo contenga.

Comment: Es erróneo lo que dices, ya que si usamos *%* para el *height* entonces el porcentaje a tomar en cuenta será el alto del padre, independientemente del porcentaje del ancho, lo que hace que se pierda la relación de aspecto *2:1*

Comment: Lo que básicamente busco, es poder hacer referencia al ancho del elemento padre dentro del alto del hijo.

Answer (score 4):

Por lo que logro entender... `.terrain` debe mantener la relación de aspecto siempre.

***Antes de saltarme algo...

VW es el ancho del viewport...

para el alto, usamos VH... viewport height***

Si tenemos un contenedor con ancho X, da lo mismo que medida usemos,
Podemos darle el % al contenedor hijo, y mantener la relación de aspecto.

Creo entender, por 2:1 que `.terrain` debe ser la mitad del padre...

```css
.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
        background-color: blue;
}
.terrain{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
        background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="terrain">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Pero si usasemos otro tamaño, se veria como:

```css
.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
        background-color: blue;
}
.terrain{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
        background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="terrain">
            Hijo
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```js
console.log("widthC:" + document.getElementsByName("container")[0].offsetWidth + "px");console.log("heightC:" + document.getElementsByName("container")[0].offsetHeight + "px");
console.log("widthT:" + document.getElementsByName("terrain")[0].offsetWidth + "px");console.log("heightT:" + document.getElementsByName("terrain")[0].offsetHeight + "px");
```

```css
.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: blue;
}
.terrain{
    width: 50vw;
    height: calc(100vw - 50vw);
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container" name="container">
        <div class="terrain" name="terrain">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: 2:1 es la relación de aspecto (de hecho es la manera correcta de escribirlo). Si el ancho de .terrain mide 100, el alto mide 50... respecto a tu solución, no debe ser la mitad del padre, sino que se usa el ancho (en vw) del padre para mantener la relación de aspecto del hijo. En tu caso diste 50% al ancho y alto del hijo si cambias el tamaño del padre ( por ejemplo width:500px y height:100) el hijo no va mantener la relación de aspecto 2:1

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado pero sí te queda claro que el `height` debería usar `vh` y no `vw`?. Porque en tu código es el valor que estás usando para el alto. A menos que quieras revisar la funcion [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/calc())

Comment: @JheymanMejia, me queda tan claro como que tu "*debería*" es erróneo. Cuando usas **vh** haces referencia a un tamaño en especifico como lo es el **ancho del viewport** sin importar donde lo uses, ya sea en el width o el height. De hecho deje un comentario muy claro explicando el porqué se hizo uso del **vw** en el **height** al momento de formular la pregunta.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado Ok. Si crees que vh (viewport HEIGHT) hace referencia al ancho de la ventana, es tu decisión, eso no indica que la respuesta de Excorpion y su uso sea incorrecto.

Comment: Creo que mas de uno hace mal uso de las propiedades del viewport. Nadie dijo que vh haga referencia al ancho de la ventana. *Lo estás suponiendo*. Así como también supones que por el hecho de usar la propiedad *height* debamos usar *vh* forzosamente, y ahí es donde reside tu error porque simplemente, en el alto de mi elemento hijo *no quiero hacer referencia al alto del viewport, sino al ancho*. Te cito: `@VíctorHugoTirado pero sí te queda claro que el height debería usar vh y no vw?` Este es tu error.

Comment: Respecto a la pregunta de @Excorpion, el respondió a lo que él entendió y le agradezco que se haya tomado la molestia, el código que el escribió no es erróneo pero simplemente no responde la pregunta porque no es la solución al problema planteado, y el primer comentario lo explica. Si cambio el ancho y alto del padre, el hijo pierde su relación de aspecto 2:1

Comment: Pasando de alto su discusión. Acabo de agregar un edit. Que creo que es lo mejor que puedes lograr usando CSS. Puedes realizar cálculos de los anchos y largos, de tal modo que obtendrás diferentes valores. He usado algo de JS SOLO para mostrar los valores.
Por lo que... más allá de eso, tu respuesta sería NO. No se puede obtener mejor resultado con CSS, en ese caso solo deberías usar JS para obtener y calcular dichos anchos y altos.